# Running `sudo nmap` through snap, while allowing to write to user's home dir

Tags: snap, nmap

I have a problem running nmap in such a way that all the following requirements are satisfied:

- I want to install nmap through snap
- I want to run nmap with sudo (the scan type I want to run requires root permissions)
- I want to write output to the current directory (in the user's home directory)

These requirements seem fairly simple, but I don't succeed in setting this up in the right way.

Just running nmap gives a permission error, even after running 'snap connect nmap:home'.

```
$ sudo /snap/bin/nmap -oN file
Failed to open normal output file file for writing: Permission denied (13)
```

Is this something that's possible to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

If you run a snap under `sudo` then you're running it under `root` user, not your user. The `home` interface won't help you here. That gives the snap running as the user the ability to access that user's home.

The following works:

```
export FILENAME=/root/filename
sudo /snap/bin/nmap -oN "$FILENAME"
sudo mv "$FILENAME" .
```

Another option is to bind mount a folder.

```
mkdir ~/nmap
sudo mkdir /root/nmap
sudo mount -o bind /root/nmap /home/user/nmap
sudo /snap/bin/nmap -oN /root/nmap/nmapfile
ls ~/nmap
nmapfile
```

Comment: Thanks, good suggestion. However it would be great if I can write the output directly to the folder belonging to the current pentest, which is in the user's home. Is there no way to accomplish that?

Comment: Added another option.